# Concat JS not working

Tags: javascript, string, concatenation

```
var myjson = '{"name": "cluster","children": [';

for (var i = 0; i < unique.length; i++)
{
    var uniquepart = '{"' + unique[i] + '"';
    myjson.concat(uniquepart); 
    var sizepart = ', "size:"';
    myjson.concat(sizepart);
    var countpart = count[i] + '';
    myjson.concat(countpart);
    if (i == unique.length) {
        myjson.concat(" },");
    }
    else {
        myjson.concat(" }");
    }
} 

var ending = "]}";
myjson.concat(ending);

console.log(myjson);
```

Does anyone know why this string doesn't concat properly and I still end up with the original value?

Comment: **Don't do this**.  Instead, use `JSON.stringify`, which (a) works, (b) is faster, and (c) will actually produce valid JSON.

Comment: @SLaks to be honest, concat really isn't bad. The difference in this question is that JSON is being concatted. Your comment would be better expressed as "Don't do this if you're trying to concatenate JSON"

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The `concat()` method is used to join two or more strings.

**Definition and Usage**
This method does not change the existing strings, but returns a new string containing the text of the joined strings.
Ref: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_concat_string.asp

For example:

```
myjson = myjson.concat(uniquepart);
```

OR

```
myjson += uniquepart;
```

Answer (score 9):

A javascript string is immutable so `concat` can only return a new value, not change the initial one. If you want to append to a string you have as variable, simply use

```
myjson += "some addition";
```

Comment: This work but when I tried to  add "," symbol it may shows NaN

Answer (score 2):

[`string.concat()`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_concat_string.asp) does not modify the original string it instead returns a new string.

In order to modify it you would need to perform:

```
string = string.concat('fragment');
```

Answer (score 1):

Strings are immutable.

`.concat()` returns a **new** string, which you ignore.